# Как запустить телеграм-бота из импортированной библиотеки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, многопоточность, потоки-данных, распараллеливание

Мне необходимо запускать несколько телеграм-ботов с одинаковым функционалом одновременно. Питон, библиотека telebot.
Я хочу сделать это следующим образом: файл с програмой бота импортируется в основную программу и боты запускаются путём вызова соответствующей функции с токеном в качестве параметра.
И уже в основной программе я буду запускать несколько потоков с разными токенами. Но я столкнулся с проблемой:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot=None
token=None

def start_bot(token):
    global bot
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет")
```

Сейчас функция start ищет декоратор bot и не находит его, либо находит None. Ошибка.

Я пробовал задавать случайный токен бота изначально, а потом его изменять при помощи функции start_bot. Не работает, декораторы сохраняют привязку к старому токену.

Единственный рабочий вариант - закатать всю программу в одну функцию и вызывать уже её, но это явно не вариант. Как можно решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтоб решить проблему для начала разбермся, как работают декораторы и как обработчики привязываются к боту.

Есть объект типа TeleBot, у которого есть функции типа message_handler. Каждая такая функция создает декоратор. Такой декоратор добавляет функцию, на которую его навесили в список обработчиков внутри объекта TeleBot.

Обычно это работает так, что есть глобальный объект бота и во время импорта модуля выполняются декораторы и обработчики регистрируются (т.е. добавляются к боту).

Теперь вы хотите создать несколько объектов бота. Это значит, что нужно каждую функцию обработчик регистрировать для каждого объекта бота. Регистрация во время импорта не будеть работать. Для кода, который вы привели (где бот создается в фукнции) на момент импорта модуля, объект бота еще не существует. Здачит и `bot.message_handler` нельзя вызвать в принципе.

Вторая проблема - модуль импортируется один раз, значит и регистрация происходит один раз. А вам нужно ее делать для каждого экземпляра бота.

Ну и третья проблема - обработчики используют объект бот уже после регистрации, например, для отсылки сообщений с помощью `send_message`. Даже если мы правильно зарегистрируем обработчик для разных ботом, если обработчик один, то ему нужно каким-то образом находить у какого-же экзепляра бота вызывать метод `send_message`.

Далее обсужу варианты решения. Я рассматриваю только функцию запуска одного экземпляра бота `start_bot`. Нужно ее запустить в отдельных потоках столько раз, сколько нужно с разными токенами.

### Одна функция

Вы написали, что это не вариант. Но это как раз самый простой вариант, с одним небольшим минусом - чуть хуже читаемость кода из-за подолнительного отступа.

```
def start_bot(token):
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет")

    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

### Ручная регистрация обработчиков

В этом способе вызываем регистрацию вручную. Это нужно сделать для каждого обработчика до запуска `polling`. Дополнительно нужно в обработчик передать объект бота:

```
from functools import partial

def start_bot(token):
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
    bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])(partial(start, bot))
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)

def start(bot, message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет")
```

### thread local переменные + обертка

Самый сложный способ, но позволяет не менять способ задания обработчиков. Суть в том, что мы создаем один объект обертку `BotWrapper`, в котором есть своя функция `message_handler`. Она тоже создает декоратор, но он не регистрирует обработчик в каком-то конктретном экземпляре бота, а сохраняет его с список. При создании же конкретного бота производится регистрация. Таким образом решается проблема с регистрацией для каждого бота.

Проблема с доступом к экзепляру бота решается таким образом, что при создании бот сохраняется в threadlocal хранилище. В обработчике доступ идет через обертку, которая достает бот из этого хранилища, т.е. в каждом потоке свой экземпляр и уже ему перенаправляет вызов. Схематически решение выглядит так:

```
import threading

class BotWrapper:

    def __init__(self):
        self.handlers = []
        self.threadlocal = threading.local()

    def start_bot(token):
        bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
        self.threadlocal.bot = bot
        for handler_func, args, kwargs in self.handlers:
           bot.message_handler(*args, **kwargs)(handler_func)
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)

    def message_handler(self, *args, **kwars):
        def wrapper(f):
            self.handlers.append = (f, *args, **kwargs)
            return f
        return wrapper

    # это будет перенаправлять все неизвестные методы
    # к конктретному экземпляру бота
    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        return getattr(self.threadlocal.bot, method_name)

bot = BotWrapper()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет")
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему при помощи вот такой функции. Спасибо @roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua за решение.

```
def start_program(nbot,token):
    global bot_name, bot
    bot_name,bot = nbot, telebot.TeleBot(token)
    
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def answer_bot(call):
        answer(bot,call)
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def func_bot(message):
        func(bot,message)
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start_bot(message):
        start(bot,message)
    
    print(nbot,token)
    
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```